# HTTP 404 While Deploying a Basic Web App

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying to learn the basics of RichFaces with basic tutorials over the internet. I'm Using this Development Environment:

1. Eclipse Helios Service Release 2 (Build Id: 20110218-0911)
2. Glassfish Open Source Edition 3.1
   (Plugin Installed in eclipse).
3. RichFaces 4.0.0 Final (jar's added
   in WEB-INF/lib in my project)

But, while i'm trying to deploy the webapp with Glassfish, i get the error: HTTP 404 Not Found:

> The requested resource
>   (/JSFR4/test.jsf) is not available.

I know it's an "File Not Found" error, but, the problem is that i'm getting the same error in any application what i'm doing, and i don't know what is wrong. In the Glassfish Administration Console the webapp is deployed, and, when i'm launching it from this console, i'm getting the same error.

The server.log doesn't log any error.

Can You help me? What i'm doing wrong?

Here is the web.xml generated for the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <description>Facelets StarterKit</description>
  <display-name>JSFR4</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>2</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is the faces-config generated for the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <description>Facelets StarterKit</description>
  <display-name>JSFR4</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>2</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And This, is my xhtml file (Very simple)

```
<f:view>
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <rich:panel header="RichFaces Example">
            <ul>
                <li>This is an Example of Richfaces</li>
                <li>A JSF Library</li>
            </ul>
        </rich:panel>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

Thanks to Everyone

Comment: does it work with `/faces/...` instead of `.jsf` ?

Comment: @Bozho No, it doesn't Work. I'm tried the url: http://localhost:8081/faces/ and i'm get the same error.

Comment: @Bozho Also, i've tried: http://localhost:8081/faces/test.jsf (and test.xhtml), and i'm still having the issue. In the web.xml, the default path is: /faces/*, why can't work?

Comment: and `http://localhost:8081/JSFR4/faces/test` ?

Comment: Sadly, no, that's what i'm get: http://imageshack.us/f/804/404w.png/ - And this is the status of the webapp in the Glassfish Administration Console: http://imageshack.us/f/151/glassfish.png/

Comment: where is your text.xhtml located?

Comment: It's located in WEB-INF/test.xhtml - WEB-INF is the DocumentRoot, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.xhtml` files should normally go in the root of the context. Something like:

```
webapps/
    yourapp/
        WEB-INF/
        test.xhtml
        foo.xhtml
```

Comment: Ok, you're Right! I'm trying to run the webapp placing the Facelets (xhtml's) in a wrong location. Newbie Error. Thanks for you time and your patience!